# Unexpected effect of implicit cast on delegate type inference

Tags: c#, delegates, type-inference

I have a simple `Money` type with an implicit cast from `decimal`:

```
struct Money
{
    decimal innerValue;
    public static implicit operator Money(decimal value)
    {
        return new Money { innerValue = value };
    }
    public static explicit operator decimal(Money value)
    {
        return value.innerValue;
    }

    public static Money Parse(string s)
    {
        return decimal.Parse(s);
    }
}
```

And I defined a `Sum()` overload to operate on those values:

```
static class MoneyExtensions
{
    public static Money Sum<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, Money> selector)
    {
        return source.Select(x => (decimal)selector(x)).Sum();
    }
}
```

What I didn't expect was for this extension method to interfere with the existing `Sum()` extension methods:

```
var source = new[] { "2" };
Money thisWorks = source.Sum(x => Money.Parse(x));
int thisWorksToo = source.Sum(new Func<string, int>(x => int.Parse(x)));
int thisDoesNot = source.Sum(x => int.Parse(x));
```

The error is "Cannot implicitly convert type 'Money' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)". Is it correct that the compiler favors `int => decimal => Money` implicit conversions over resolving an overload that's an exact match?

Comment: The `int` overload of `Sum()` in System.Linq.

Comment: Can you provide a complete example that generates that compile-error?  You haven't shown your `using`-declarations, which are very important in this situation.

Comment: Can't edit the question at work, so... `using System; using System.Collections.Generic; using System.Linq;`

Comment: I see your point +1, those using declarations are part of the default

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the C# 4.0 Specification, section 7.6.5.2:

> The preceding rules mean that instance methods take precedence over extension methods, that extension methods available in inner namespace declarations take precedence over extension methods available in outer namespace declarations, and that extension methods declared directly in a namespace take precedence over extension methods imported into that same namespace with a using namespace directive

Probably, this is causing your Money Sum extension method to take precedence over the ones from Linq - that's why you don't get an "ambiguous method call" error.

Comment: So it should work if I move my `Sum()` method into a different namespace?

Comment: @dahlbyk: yes - it should work if the root namespace of the extension method class is different from where your test code is executing.

Answer (score 2):

Following on from Rob Siklos's research, (please vote up the research)
Putting the extension in a seperate namespace fixes this problem. I seem to recall this as one of the guidelines for extensions.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Extensions;

namespace Currency
{
    struct Money
    {          
        decimal innerValue;
        public static implicit operator Money(decimal value)
        {
            return new Money { innerValue = value };
        }
        public static explicit operator decimal(Money value)
        {
            return value.innerValue;
        }
        public static Money Parse(string s)
        {
        return decimal.Parse(s);
        }
     }

     class Program
     {
         static void Main()
         {
             var source = new[] { "2" };
             Money thisWorks = source.Sum(x => Money.Parse(x));
             int thisWorksToo = 
                 source.Sum(new Func<string, int>(x => int.Parse(x)));       
             int thisWorksTooNow = source.Sum(x => int.Parse(x));

         }
     }
}
namespace Extensions
{
    static class IEnumerableTExtensions
    {
        public static Currency.Money Sum<TSource>(
                                       this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
                                       Func<TSource, Currency.Money> selector)
        {
            return source.Select(x => (decimal)selector(x)).Sum();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's because you are explicitly declaring `thisDoesNot` as type `int`. If you use implicit declaration, it works fine:

```
void Main()
{
    var source = new[] { "2" };
    Money thisWorks = source.Sum(x => Money.Parse(x));
    int thisWorksToo = source.Sum(new Func<string, int>(x => int.Parse(x)));
    var thisDoesNot = source.Sum(x => int.Parse(x));

    Console.Write(thisDoesNot.GetType());
}
```

From the [specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691356%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> The method group identifies the one
>   method to invoke or the set of
>   overloaded methods from which to
>   choose a specific method to invoke. **In
>   the latter case, determination of the
>   specific method to invoke is based on
>   the context provided by the types of
>   the arguments in the argument-list**.

Comment: It compiles, but `thisDoesNot` has type `Money` instead of `int`. In the real scenario, I have a cart of items with `Money Price` and `int Quantity` - a `Sum()` on `Quantity` returning `int` fails to compile.

Comment: That specification is for VS 2003, before extension methods were around.

Comment: @Rob it may be an old link, but c# 4.0 was built upon this foundation and member look up is still the same.

Comment: @scottm: not true - there is different resolution logic for extension methods (see my answer to this question)

Comment: @Rob: Is to! =P The 3.0 spec where extension methods are introduced http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364047(v=vs.80).aspx#cs3spec_topic3 references back to the 7.5.5.1 quote I posted. However, I think your answer is correct.