# Why does Assert.AreEqual on custom struct with implicit conversion operator fail?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, struct, implicit-conversion

I've created a custom struct to represent an amount. It is basically a wrapper around `decimal`. It has an implicit conversion operator to cast it back to `decimal`.

In my unit test, I assert that the Amount equals the original decimal value, but the test fails.

```
[TestMethod]
public void AmountAndDecimal_AreEqual()
{
    Amount amount = 1.5M;

    Assert.AreEqual(1.5M, amount);
}
```

When I use an int though (for which I did not create a conversion operator), the test *does* succeed.

```
[TestMethod]
public void AmountAndInt_AreEqual()
{
    Amount amount = 1;

    Assert.AreEqual(1, amount);
}
```

When I hover the `AreEqual`, it shows that the first one resolves to

```
public static void AreEqual(object expected, object actual);
```

and the second one leads to

```
public static void AreEqual<T>(T expected, T actual);
```

It looks like the `int` value `1` is implicitly cast to an `Amount`, while the `decimal` value `1.5M` is not.

I don't understand why this happens. I would've expected just the opposite. The first unit test should be able to cast the `decimal` to an `Amount`.

When I add an implicit cast to `int` (which wouldn't make sense), the second unit test also fails. So adding an implicit cast operator breaks the unit test.

I have two questions:

1. What is the explanation for this behavior?
2. How can I fix the `Amount` struct so both tests will succeed?

*(I know I could change the test to do an explicit conversion, but if I don't absolutely have to, I won't)*

My Amount struct (just a minimal implementation to show the problem)

```
public struct Amount
{
    private readonly decimal _value;

    private Amount(decimal value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator Amount(decimal value)
    {
        return new Amount(value);
    }

    public static implicit operator decimal(Amount amount)
    {
        return amount._value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your both operators are `implicit`. So, should it be `AreEqual<decimal>` or `AreEqual<Amount>`?

Comment: @PetSerAl is right. if you use `AreEqual<decimal>` or `AreEqual<Amount>` it will pass.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bad things happen when you can convert `implicit`ly in both directions, and this is one example.

Because of the implicit conversions the compiler is able to pick `Assert.AreEqual<decimal>(1.5M, amount);` and `Assert.AreEqual<Amount>(1.5M, amount);` with equal value.*

Since they're equal, neither overload will be picked by inference.

Since there's no overload to pick by inference, neither make it into the list for picking the best-match and only the `(object, object)` form is available. So it's the one picked.

With `Assert.AreEqual(1, amount)` then since there is an implicit conversion from `int` to `Amount` (via implicit int->decimal) but no implicit conversion from `Amount` to `int` the compiler thinks "obviously they mean the `Assert.AreEqual<Amount>()` here"†, and so it is picked.

You can explicitly pick an overload with `Assert.AreEqual<Amount>()` or `Assert.AreEqual<decimal>()` but you're probably better off making one of your conversions the "narrowing" from that has to be `explicit` if at all possible because this feature of your struct will hurt you again. (Hurrah for unit tests finding flaws).

---

*Another valid overload choice is to pick `Assert.AreEqual<object>`, but it's never picked by inference because:

1. Both the rejected overloads were considered even better.
2. It is always beaten by the non-generic form that takes `object` anyway.

As such it can only ever be called by including the `<object>` in the code.

†The compiler treats everything said to it as either obvious in meaning or completely incomprehensible. There are people like that too.

Comment: Thanks for your ellaborate answer. I my case, the `implicit` cast back to `decimal` was not really needed, so I changed it to be `explicit`. I wonder though, how I could have found out by myself why AreEqual(object, object) is being called. There are no compiler errors, but it is just not doing what I expected. Any tips on that? Can you somehow see some sort of decision tree for the compiler?

Comment: @comecme if I'm confused by an overload selection I first write some methods that match the signature (so here I'd have created maybe an `AssertAreEqual(object x, object y)` and `AssertAreEqual<T>(T x, T y)`. Then confirm that I get the same behaviour (the object form is taken), then delete the one picked an see what happens: `CS0411 The type arguments for method 'AssertAreEqual<T>(T, T)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`. Wondering why they couldn't be inferred would be a big clue. Now when I go to specify explicitly I've the question…

Comment: … should I explicitly say `<decimal>` or explicitly say `<Amount>`? A ha! I don't know, so how can the compiler? Problem ID'd. The big problem though is that I'm a fresh pair of eyes looking at your code without having a plan for it in mind which makes that last mental jump easier to make. When it's ones own code one has a plan in mind and it can be harder to see why what is obvious to the person who made that plan isn't to the compiler. The only thing to do about that is to go and have a cup of coffee and a walk about and come back to it for a fresher look.